# Sort 2D array by last value in each inner array

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array of arrays and all of the inner-arrays contain 4 strings and an int.

Right now, I am traveling through the arrays with a `foreach` and I am looking for help sorting the inner arrays by the number ( the last item ) so that the higher / larger ones are first and then transferring them into a new array that is sorted in that manner.

```
$twoDUnsorted = array(
    array(
        0=>"the",
        1=>"quick",
        2=>"brown",
        3=>"fox",
        4=>650
    ),
    array(
        0=>"jumps",
        1=>"over",
        2=>"the",
        3=>"lazy",
        4=>420
    ),
    array(
        0=>"it",
        1="was",
        2=>"the",
        3=>"worst"
        4=>1016
    ),
    array(
        0=>"of",
        1=>"times",
        2=>"it",
        3=>"was",
        4=>768
    ),
    array(
        0=>"the",
        1=>"best",
        2=>"of",
        3=>"times,
        4=>123
   )
);
```

and then one travels through it with a for each, sorts it by the last item in each inner array, and then uses array_push to push the arrays into a new 2D array in order.

So the new 2D array would look like:

```
$twoDSorted = array(
    array(
        0=>"it",
        1="was",
        2=>"the",
        3=>"worst"
        4=>1016
    ),
    array(
        0=>"of",
        1=>"times",
        2=>"it",
        3=>"was",
        4=>768
    ),
    array(
        0=>"the",
        1=>"quick",
        2=>"brown",
        3=>"fox",
        4=>650
    ),
    array(
        0=>"jumps",
        1=>"over",
        2=>"the",
        3=>"lazy",
        4=>420
    ),
    array(
        0=>"the",
        1=>"best",
        2=>"of",
        3=>"times,
        4=>123
   )
);

I would appreciate any and all help sorting them and pushing them into the new array in order.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `usort()` to sort the array however you'd like, and `end()` gets the last value in the array etc. so this would sort the array of arrays by the last index in each array, highest first :

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if (end($a) == end($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (end($a) > end($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($twoDUnsorted, "cmp");
```

Comment: Very cool and super easy. Could you please explain what this syntax does a bit more? return (end($a) > end($b)) ? -1 : 1;

Comment: [**usort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) will sort an array based on, well anything really? I "borrowed" the above code straight from the first example in the documentation, and just added [**end()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to sort by the last value in each array, and reversed the order.

Comment: The return statement just checks if the current value in the sort function is higher than the previous, and returns -1 or 1, as is the usual practice for sorting functions in many languages, also in javascript etc.

Comment: Very nice! Love the simplicity!

Comment: Thank you for explaining that line and thank you for the solution.
I have one question. How does giving usort a string for the second argument connect it with the function with the name of that string. And, one more thing, currently I believe it rewrites the old 2D array. How can I get it to write the values into a new 2D array, which is sorted?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a multi-dimensional sort function.  I think the third example on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) should help you.